# Call delegate function in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a `iOS` app I am creating in `XCode`, I have a main interface, and a function delegate:

```
- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSString *infoString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
    return NO;
}
```

.. and I'm using this function to listen to incoming packets. It runs as expected the first time, but after a device lock/unlock sequence, that is after a `applicationWillEnterForeground` call, it seems to stop working.

How can I have it called?

Comment: What library are you using for `AsyncUdpSocket`?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty obvious that you won't receive any packets because when you Lock your device, the app enters the background mode and in Background mode, your app cannot receive any data packets from internet. There are two around solutions to your problem:

1. You have to maintain client-server packets send/ receive using packet Acknowledgement method. When the app reaches background your app won't send the ack to the server so server knows from to send the data once the app requests again. For app to send the request again, make the request again in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.
2. This approach will only work if your app is of following types-

   - Music Player App
   - Navigation App
   - VoIP App
   - Newsstand app
   - App with External Accessory

In this case your app can send/ receive data even in the background. For more details have a look at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: They're not asking about receiving data in the background. As @user2016803 has mentioned, they're talking about after `applicationWillEnterForeground` call.

Comment: Then approach 1 would be the solution. I just gave the second approach  as an around way option

Comment: I disagree. UDP is connectionless and therefore is listening to broadcasted packets. In this case it's not necessary to request for anything unless the user specifically wants to receive any missed packets. You would be correct if we were talking about TCP, however.

Comment: Then only make the request for new packets. Don't request for old packets. but still approach remains same as I explained

Comment: Again, with UDP there is no packet acknowledgement, that's what TCP does. I will leave requesting missed data out of this because that information is not pertinent to the question asked.

Comment: All you need to do is make the request in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application method. Let me know how you are making the initial request.

Comment: I use class AsyncUdpSocket to send/recive packets
</br>http://www.mediafire.com/?w620aa7av6uuvi4
</br>http://www.mediafire.com/?9zut34pwuyvgut2
and MainInterface

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated // THIS USE WHEN UIVIEW CONTROLLER APPEAR
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];  
    
    int port2 = 8080; 
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    // init server get SEARCHING REPLY command
    if (isUdpServerSearchingPrinterRunning == NO) {
        
        if (![udpSocket_searching_printer bindToPort:port2 error:&error]){
// Error starting the UDP server;
            return;
        }
        [udpSocket_searching_printer receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
//UDP server started on port 8080"
        isUdpServerSearchingPrinterRunning = YES;
    }
    
}

Comment: - (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSString *infoString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
    return NO;
}

Comment: Simply do the same stuff that you are doing in viewDidAppear for making the request in the  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application method of AppDelegate. Let me know if the problem still persists

Comment: Hi EvolGate
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController viewDidAppear:TRUE];
}
It only call viewDidAppear, and can not receive any packets.
I have use udp test tool to send 
Please help

Comment: You should not call viewDidLoad explicitly like this. Write a new  method or simply write the request code inside the didBecomeActive method.

Comment: I have create a task sample viewDidAppear in applicationDidBecomeActive, but function (BOOL)onUdpSocket can not active so packets have been send, but no recive, how to that function alway active ?